# How can i pass scope in template in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I have one `BaseController` with common functions which my all other controllers inherit .

The controller is like this

```
function BaseController () {

    this.defaultFilters = {};

    this.doStuff = function ($scope) {
        $scope.myobj.value = 1;
        this.otherfunction();
    };
```

I inherit that in my controller like this

`BaseController.call($scope);`

Now in my do stuff function i need to pass $scope because myobj is only visible there.

Now i want to know that how can i pass that in my template because i want to call that function when some click on some button

`ng-click="doStuff(scope)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything that you associate with your controller's scope, so you just associate your scope with some variable and i guess that will do the job.

Something like this :

```
    app.controller(function($scope) {
        $scope.scope = $scope;

    });
```

But if you go by some standard approach, i suggest moving these common functions inside some service, injecting this service into each controller and using it in the views.

Something like this :

```
    app.service("constantService", function() {

        this.data = {}; // This will represent your common data.

        this.commonFunction = function() {

        };

    });


    app.controller(function() {
        $scope.constantService = constantService;


        // You can now use $scope.constantService.data as your reference for data, and then can copy it to some local $scope variable whenever required.
    });


    ng-click="constantService.commonFunction()"
```

Comment: thanks for that . Suppose if i use service , then what to do in the case where i need to modify $scope variable in that function. i can't do that in service

Comment: Why would you do that, if you store your data in service itself. See, My suggestion is to move your associated data as well as common code in service(s), so that they become globally accessible and modifying them at one place modifies them everywhere..

Comment: thanks for that , Actually i was always confsued how to put all stuff in services but i haven't found solid example for best practices , from internet , where someone has shown how to do all stuff in services. Do you know any online link , so that i can see how people put stuff in services

Comment: Well, everything i posted came out from personal experiments. You better start implementing stuff, and look for the solutions you face while doing the same. You can always post a question in case of any issues..